# Android: Set shadow/radius on ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-custom-view

I was wondering if there is a way to set a shadow or radius around the text that is displayed by the ViewPager or its PagerStrip

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/mainroot"
     >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"


                android:shadowColor="#000" ???
                android:shadowRadius="3.0" ???



        >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:id="@+id/pagerTabStrip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"


                android:shadowColor="#000" ???
                android:shadowRadius="3.0" ???





            />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Did anyone achieve this somehow?